# Windows Phone 8 LiveConnectClient BackgroundUploadAsync error: Operation is not valid

Tags: c#, file-upload, windows-phone-8, onedrive

I'm writing a windows phone 8 app that uploads files to the user's OneDrive using backgrounduploadasync. The program works great when it is the foreground app. I am using the live SDK signin button for them to enter their credentials. I am using a ResourceIntensiveTask that is supposed to run and cleanup any files that didn't get uploaded while the app was running. The task runs fine. The only error I get is when I try to upload the files. Please keep in mind that almost all of the code that uploads files is shared between foreground app and background task so it should work fine. The only difference is how I log in to OneDrive. Now I am using the InitializeAsync approach.

```
// This all works fine
LiveAuthClient auth = new LiveAuthClient("ABC...123"); // my ClientId
Task<LiveLoginResult> t = auth.InitializeAsync(new string[] { "wl.signin wl.skydrive wl.skydrive_update wl.offline_access" });
LiveLoginResult res = t.Result;
_client = new LiveConnectClient(auth.Session);
```

Here is where I upload the file. This code works great as long as I'm the foreground app.

```
// Here is where I get the InvalidOperationException
LiveOperationResult res = await _client.BackgroundUploadAsync(onedriveFolderId,
                        new Uri("/shared/transfers/" + file.Name, UriKind.Relative),
                        OverwriteOption.Rename);
```

Any ideas as to why it works great when I'm in the foreground but not during the ResourceIntensiveTask? Here is the exception I get:

A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll

Invalid operation: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

Stack Trace:
at Microsoft.Phone.BackgroundTransfer.BackgroundTransferRequest.SubmitHelper()
at Microsoft.Phone.BackgroundTransfer.BackgroundTransferRequest.Submit()
at Microsoft.Phone.BackgroundTransfer.BackgroundTransferService.Add(BackgroundTransferRequest request)
at Microsoft.Live.Phone.PhoneBackgroundTransferService.Add(BackgroundTransferRequest request)
at Microsoft.Live.Phone.Operations.BackgroundUploadOperation.d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

Answer (score 0):

Live SDK uses BackgroundTransfer API underneath the BackgroundUploadAsync API. Unfortunately, it listed as unsupported when running in background Agent context.
See this doc: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202962(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202962%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)